# Using Shopify Storefront API to fetch Collection Image

Tags: ionic3, shopify, graphql-js

I'm building an Shopify Ionic 3 App using the Storefront API.
Fetching ID and Title works. But trying to access Image it fails.

Using "GraphiQL" with this Query

```
{
  shop {
    collections(first: 1) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          handle
          image {
            originalSrc
          }
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
}
```

will Result with

```
{
  "data": {
    "shop": {
      "collections": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Db2xsZWN0aW9uLzM2NTUwNjY5OQ==",
              "title": "Snacks",
              "handle": "snacks-co",
              "image": {
                "originalSrc": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2262/0831/collections/Snacks_Collection.jpg?v=1524511173"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "pageInfo": {
          "hasNextPage": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using "graphql-js-client" with Ionic 3, Collection Image is not available.

```
// Service Provider Function
getCollectionsWithImage() {
  let query = this.client.query((root) => {
    root.add('shop', (shop) => {
      shop.addConnection('collections', {args: {first: 16}}, (collection) => {
        collection.add('id');
        collection.add('title');

        // THIS does not work
        // collection.add('image', (image) => {
        //     image.add('originalSrc');
        // })

       // THIS does not work
        // collection.addConnection('image', (image) => {
        //     image.add('originalSrc');
        // })                  
       })
    })
  });

  return this.client.send(query).then(({model, data}) => {
    return model.shop.collections;
  });
}
```

Do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. After running Introspection Query against the Storefront API refreshed all nodes in my types.js. Now i'm able to access Collection Images, too.